# Finding numbers whose digits sum to $7$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Question**
[A number is "lucky" if the sum of its digits is $7$. If the $n$-th lucky number is $2014$, then what is the $(n/6)$-th lucky number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4485810/a-number-is-lucky-if-the-sum-of-its-digits-is-7-if-the-n-th-lucky-number)

A number is "lucky" if the sum of its digits is $7$. If the $n$-th lucky number is $2014$, then what is the $(n/6)$-th lucky number?

**MY solution using brute force and sequence**

The first number of this sequence is 7 and 2nd is 16 . I make a ap sequence from 7 to 70 . Then make  another ap sequence from 106 to 160 . Again from 205 to 250 , similarly 304 to 340  ........
with the help of
http://oeis.org/A052221/b052221.txt

here n is 66 and n/6 is 11 .

**My Question**
What is the efficient way to find the value of n .
Thank you.

Comment: I'd use Stars and Bars to count the "good" numbers with $k$ digits.  That should let you find $n$ pretty quickly.

Comment: How did this get 8 upvotes within 6 minutes?

Comment: @Randall sorry sir . But I found this question from a user account and trying to find the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Number of ${\color{Red}{2}}$ digit numbers whose sum of digits is ${\color{Blue}{7}}$ = $\binom{{\color{Red}{2}}+
{\color{Blue}{7}}-1}{{\color{Red}{2}}-1} = 8.$

Number of ${\color{Red}{3}}$ digit numbers whose sum of digits is ${\color{Blue}{7}}$ = $\binom{{\color{Red}{3}}+
{\color{Blue}{7}}-1}{{\color{Red}{3}}-1}-8 = 28.$

Number of ${\color{Red}{4}}$ digit numbers which starts with $1$ and thus sum of remaining digits is ${\color{Blue}{6}}$ = $\binom{{\color{Red}{4-1}}+
{\color{Blue}{6}}-1}{{\color{Red}{4-1}}-1} = 28.$

Now, we can observe that $65 ^{\text{th}}$ lucky number = $2005$ and $\boxed{66 ^{\text{th}} \text{ lucky number} = 2014}$.